# R equivalent of Stata `tabulate , generate( )` command

Tags: r, stata, dummy-variable

I want to mimic the behavior of Stata's `tabulate , generate()` command in R. It is illustrated below; the command's functionality is twofold. First, in my example, it produces a one-way table of frequency counts. Second, it generated dummy variables for each of the values contained on the variable (`var1`) using the prefix (*stubname*) declared in option `,generate()` to name the generated dummy variables (`d_1 - d_7`). My question is regarding the second functionality. R-base solutions are preferred, but packaged dependent are also welcome.

[Edit]: My final goal is to generate a `data.frame()` that emulates the last data set printed on the screen.

```
clear all
input var1 
0
1
2
2
2
2
42
42
777
888
999999
end
tabulate var1 ,gen(d_)

/*     var1 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |          1        9.09        9.09
          1 |          1        9.09       18.18
          2 |          4       36.36       54.55
         42 |          2       18.18       72.73
        777 |          1        9.09       81.82
        888 |          1        9.09       90.91
     999999 |          1        9.09      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         11      100.00          */


list, sep(11)



/*   +--------------------------------------------------+
     |   var1   d_1   d_2   d_3   d_4   d_5   d_6   d_7 |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  1. |      0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0 |
  2. |      1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0 |
  3. |      2     0     0     1     0     0     0     0 |
  4. |      2     0     0     1     0     0     0     0 |
  5. |      2     0     0     1     0     0     0     0 |
  6. |      2     0     0     1     0     0     0     0 |
  7. |     42     0     0     0     1     0     0     0 |
  8. |     42     0     0     0     1     0     0     0 |
  9. |    777     0     0     0     0     1     0     0 |
 10. |    888     0     0     0     0     0     1     0 |
 11. | 999999     0     0     0     0     0     0     1 |
     +--------------------------------------------------+ */
```

Comment: `model.matrix(~0+x, data.frame(x = factor(1:5)))` would create the second table.

Comment: This would give you a little intro to R from Stata perspective: http://rslblissett.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RTutorial_160930.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference @EyayawB.! I'll check that. However, I updated the question to be more precise, and I suspect the solution you provided is not suitable anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(var1 = factor(sample(10, 20, TRUE)))

df = data.frame(df, model.matrix(~0+var1, df)) # 0 here is to suppress the intercept. The smallest value will be the base group--and hence will be dropped. 
names(df)[-1] = paste0('d_', 1:(ncol(df)-1))
df
    var1 d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4 d_5 d_6 d_7 d_8 d_9
1     3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2     3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3    10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
4     2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5     6   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
6     5   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
7     4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
8     6   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
9     9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
10   10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
11    5   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
12    3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13    9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
14    9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
15    9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
16    3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17    8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
18   10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
19    7   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
20   10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are assuming each value in `var_1` is unique so that you get dummy variables rather than counts in the `d_` fields.

You could try something like this:

```
var1 <- 1:5
dummy_matrix <- vapply(var1, function(x) as.numeric(var1 == x), rep(1, 5)) # create a matrix of dummy vars
colnames(dummy_matrix) <- paste0("d_", var1) # name the columns
cbind(var1, dummy_matrix) # bind to var1
```

Output:

```
  var1 d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4 d_5
1    1   1   0   0   0   0
2    2   0   1   0   0   0
3    3   0   0   1   0   0
4    4   0   0   0   1   0
5    5   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the example to avoid misconceptions. To be concrete, values in `var_1` doesn't have to be unique necessarily. Additionally, the number of different values contained in `var_1` is unknown apriori.

Comment: I think @EyayawB.'s comment is right after all! Try something like this

`var1 <- c(0,1,2,2,2,2,42,42,777,888,999999);
dummy_matrix <- model.matrix(~0+x, data.frame(x = factor(var1)));
colnames(dummy_matrix) <- paste0("d_", seq_along(unique(var1)));
output <- data.frame(cbind(var1, dummy_matrix))`

Comment: I think you are right. If you turn this into an answer, I will accept it, and in that way, we can flag this question as solved on the system.